# Sound works 50% of the time on restart

Tags: sound

I was hoping someone could help me out with a sound issue that I'm having.  I looked for similar posts but couldn't find one that addressed this specific issue.  The problem I have is:  upon restart or bootup, my sound works about 50% of the time.  So when I start my computer, if it's working it works for everything.  Music, videos, games, etc.  Although, the other half of the time I startup my computer and it just doesn't work for anything.  So usually I have to restart once or twice for everything to be good.  I'm using Ubuntu with the cinnamon background if that matters.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First we need to see if the speakers are even loading properly.

While your speakers are working open terminal and type in `aplay -l`. If you are using dedicated speakers (not in your monitor) look at the first few cards labeled PCH. If you are using your monitor speakers look at the cards labeled HDMI. You may want to write this information down.

For example, my PC has:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1150 Analog [ALC1150 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1150 Digital [ALC1150 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

All you need to take note of right now is the card number (0 for both) and the device number (0 and 1 in this instance).

The next time you boot up and your sound isn't working open the terminal and type in `aplay -l` again. Use what you remember from the first `aplay -l` output and compare the two.

If the two outputs don't match then your device isn't being loaded. This should help narrow down the potential cause of the problem.